# what is returned when calling distance_to_line Sketchup Ruby API

Tags: ruby, sketchup

Hi all

I am trying to get the distance from one 3D point object to a line. This is my code:

```
line_x = [Geom::Point3d.new(0,0,0), Geom::Vector3d.new(1,0,0)]
a = [10,11,0]
distance_x = a.distance_to_line line_x
puts distance_x
```

This is output in Sketchup ruby console.

11"

11"

I try distance_x.typename , but it got error :undefined method `typename' for 11.0:Length

I think output of distance_to_line is a number. Why i got double of result while i just call puts in one time.
Please help me, thanks

Comment: What happens if you remove the puts statement altogether?

Comment: @Kal :It dosen't output anything in ruby console

Comment: `#typename` is a method of the Entity class.  If you want to know the type of object you have use `#class`.

Comment: Remember to accept the answer that resolved your question. It's good curtsey and how this site is used. So far you haven't accepted any answer to any of your questions. It tells the rest of the community and those who answer that you are satisfied and done with the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array.distance_to_line returns a Length.

```
line_x = [Geom::Point3d.new(0,0,0), Geom::Vector3d.new(1,0,0)]
[Point3d(0, 0, 0), Vector3d(1, 0, 0)]
a = [10,11,0]
[10, 11, 0]
distance_x = a.distance_to_line line_x
11.0
distance_x.class
Length
```

Yes, the [docs](http://www.sketchup.com/intl/en/developer/docs/ourdoc/array.php#distance_to_line) aren't very clear on the return type.

Comment: Note, a `Length` is a sub-class of `Float`. It adds comparison operators that uses SketchUp's internal tolerance and a custom `#to_s` method to format into a string using the current model unit settings. http://www.sketchup.com/intl/en/developer/docs/ourdoc/length.php

Answer (score 0):

I've used SketchUp before, but not with Ruby scripting. I've just tried it out now, and I see the console outputs the return value each time you enter a line (in addition to any puts output). But I can't reproduce exactly what you're seeing.

If I enter each line one at a time, I get `11.0` after the second last line and then this after the last line:

```
11"
nil
```

The 'nil' is what `#puts` actually returns.

If I save the script in a text editor and load it into SketchUp, I instead get this:

```
11"
true
```

'True' is the return value when 'there are no syntax errors in the file' according to the [SketchUp documentation](http://www.sketchup.com/intl/en/developer/docs/loading.php).

But as I said, I can't reproduce exactly what you're seeing.

What do you see if you change the last line to just 'distance_x' (delete the word 'puts')? For me, this just returns the value '11.0'.